# How to get current radio button index value from a radio button group in codename one?

Tags: codenameone

I have some radio button which I put in radio button group.
So,  how can I  get the radio button index value or selected index value when I going to click on a particular radio button.

Here is my code

```
 bg=new ButtonGroup();
 for(i=0;i<8;i++){
 rbt =new RadioButton();
 rbt.setName("rbt"+i);
 radioList.add(rbt);
 }
 for(int i=0;i<radioList.size();i++){
  radioList.get(i).addPointerPressedListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            for(int i=0;i<radioList.size();i++){
                                  Log.p("================"+bg.getSelectedIndex);
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
 }
```

In the above code I am getting the previously selected  value not the current. value

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

`pointerPressed` is called before the radio button has processed the event. Use `addActionListener` instead, which is fired after the state is changed, so the selected index should be the currently-selected radio button.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the radiobutton in container as well as buttongroup and call getselectedIndex of buttongroup to get current index as shown in below code

```
void testRadio(Form form) {
        Container radioList = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            RadioButton rbt = new RadioButton();
            rbt.setName("rbt" + i);
            rbt.setText("rbt" + i);
            **radioList.add(rbt);
            bg.add(rbt);**
        }
        bg.setSelected(0);
        form.add(radioList);
        Button getIndexButton = new Button("Get Radio Index");
        getIndexButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
//                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                Log.p("================" + bg.getSelectedIndex());
            }
        });
        form.add(getIndexButton);

    }
```